# vega lite expr reference mark column width

Tags: vega-lite

I have vertical column chart like this one

[image: vertical column bar chart]

The chart is set to fit into the container with 100% width.
Column with in the chart is calculated responsively by vega to fit into the container.

In additional layer I'm rendering text value labels above the columns. And I need the label to be exactly above its corresponding column. To calculate the position of a label I'm using expression:

```
 "mark": {
        "dx": {"expr": "((datum.maxGroupCount-1)*-10)+(datum.index-1)*20"},
        "dy": -5,
        "fontSize": 9,
        "type": "text"
      }
```

Instead of the defined constant `20` in the `dx` expr I need to reference the actual column `width`  so that the labels are rendered properly when size of the chart changes.

In the vega lite editor
https://vega.github.io/editor/
you can see the actual column `width` in `Data viewer` tab when you select `layer_0_marks`.

Is it possible to reference the column width?

Comment: You don't need to know column widths to set the label above the column. Just use the same data point to set the x and y co-ords. Your link doesn't show a spec either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup the text marks in a dynamic way like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "A", "group": "x", "value": 0.1},
      {"category": "A", "group": "y", "value": 0.6},
      {"category": "A", "group": "z", "value": 0.9},
      {"category": "B", "group": "x", "value": 0.7},
      {"category": "B", "group": "y", "value": 0.2},
      {"category": "B", "group": "z", "value": 1.1},
      {"category": "C", "group": "x", "value": 0.6},
      {"category": "C", "group": "y", "value": 0.1},
      {"category": "C", "group": "z", "value": 0.2}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "category", "title": null},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "title": null},
    "xOffset": {"field": "group"},
    "color": {"field": "group"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": {"type": "bar"}},
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "dy": -7},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"value": "black"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "joinaggregate": [{"op": "max", "field": "value", "as": "total"}],
          "groupby": []
        },
        {"calculate": "datum.total * 1.1", "as": "max"}
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "point", "dy": -10},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "max", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"value": "transparent"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {}
}
```

I also added an additional point layer to extend the top of the chart for the largest value. I added 10% but you can change this.

Let me know if this was useful.

[image]

Comment: Thats great solution. Thanks a lot. I was complicating things by calculating column label positions in the separate layer that was rendering the labels. I see now that the parent `encoding` deals with it.